# Multiple update conditions in one UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-update

I am working on a WPF, C# Project and using SQL server 2008. I have a table Student_2012_2013 that has a column called 'class' of varchar(10). I need to update the classes of the student at the end of every year. For example, If the class is 'Nursery', it should be updated to 'LKG', if it is 'LKG' it should be updated to 'UKG', 'UKG' should be updated to class '1', '1' to '2' and so on upto '11' to '12'.

Can I do it in one UPDATE query, or I do I need to fire 15 different update queries?

Comment: Can't you write a single query and use IF THEN statement?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `CASE` on this,

```
UPDATE  Student_2012_2013
SET     class = CASE WHEN class = 'Nursery' THEN 'LKG' 
                    WHEN class = 'LKG' THEN 'UKG'
                    WHEN class = 'UKG' THEN '1'
                    // WHEN ... continue with your conditions...
                    ELSE class // if it doesn't match to any condition
                 END
```

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal maybe, I just added `ELSE` because i was thinking if there maybe `class` in which it won't fall on any condition. but if you are sure all cases will fall in atleast on condition, then remove `ELSE`.

Comment: Thank you very much. 

I am getting the following error while executing the command with SQLCommand: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Comment: can you show your whole query? basically it's a syntax error.

Comment: `SqlCommand sda_0 = new SqlCommand("update student_2012_2013 SET class = CASE WHEN class = 'Nursery' THEN 'LKG' WHEN class = 'LKG' THEN 'UKG' WHEN class='UKG' THEN '1' WHEN '1' THEN '2' END", con);`

Comment: check you last `WHEN` you don't have condition. it should be `..WHEN class='1' THEN '2' END`

Comment: here, `update student_2012_2013 
SET class = CASE WHEN class = 'Nursery' THEN 'LKG' 
    WHEN class = 'LKG' THEN 'UKG' 
    WHEN class = 'UKG' THEN '1' 
    WHEN class = '1' THEN '2' 
   END`

Answer (score 2):

Use case statements to update the class column in your table. For Example:

```
Update Student_2012_2013 
set class = CASE 
        WHEN (CLASS = "NURSERY) THEN "LKG"
        WHEN (CLASS="LKG")THEN "UKG"
        ELSE "DEFAULT"
    END
```